# Failed to initialize PiFace Relay+

Tags: relay, pi-3b+, piface

When trying to initialize the Piface Relay+ with:

`pfr = pifacerelayplus.PiFaceRelayPlus(pifacerelayplus.RELAY)`

I get these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Documents/pifacerelayplus-master/examples/blink.py", line 9, in <module>
    pfr = pifacerelayplus.PiFaceRelayPlus(pifacerelayplus.RELAY)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pifacerelayplus/core.py", line 248, in __init__
    self.init_board(gpioa_conf, gpiob_conf)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pifacerelayplus/core.py", line 281, in init_board
    c=self.chip_select))
pifacerelayplus.core.NoPiFaceRelayPlusDetectedError: No PiFace Relay+ board detected (hardware_addr=0, bus=0, chip_select=0).`
```

My address jumpers are in the right place, SPI is enabled and I have the Python 3 libraries for Piface Relay+.

I'm using a RP3 Model B+.
Pretty new to Raspberry Pis in general so would like to know why it won't find the PiFace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explained how i solved this issue in the pifacerelayplus gitHub page. https://github.com/piface/pifacerelayplus/issues/8

Manually installing the most recent python3 distribution packages for pifacerelayplus and pifacerelay common solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have just had the exact same problem and emailed support who told me the issue is to do with upstream packages and they are planning on getting it fixed. Please see the link below for a quick fix.

https://github.com/piface/pifacecommon/commit/d4c568926e49dc75a983e2fed41b79ebf317b10d?diff=unified

Edit the `spi.py` file in the referenced directory.

Comment: Posted an explanation how i solved my issue. Don't know if we have the same issue so i don't know if it will help.